# How can I replace all elements with a string+variable in vscode?

Tags: replace, visual-studio-code

so we have these data-ui-test tags which is useful for me to write protractor tests, however all the values of said tags are the same at the moment. I want to replace all `'<input'` tags with `'<input data-ui-test = "${someVariable}"'`, I am unable to do this in the search&replace bar (ctrl+shft+f).

I am utterly clueless on how to approach the problem

Please if you have any idea on how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Is the replacement fixed, or dependent on the original (matched) text? Also including what you have used for match and replacement expressions would help.

Comment: replacement does not have to be dependent on the original text, although it would help., I have not used any expressions nor code just wrote in vscode's search bar my desired search string and then a replacement. The idea here is t find all input fields and add an html tag after them with the value of that tag being a variable. (so that i can make all tags unique.)